# can we get the list of all open urls in browser from java script

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get urls of all the tabs open in the  browser from java script...Is it any browser dependent thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you do this with javascript in a page? no, the browser sandbox will block it for security reasons.

Can you do this with a firefox add on? yes you can do this if you use jetpack on firefox. There is an api that allows you to see the tabs. It works by sitting in chrome part of firefox which has special privileges